# How to open webpage in Reader mode(Chrome) using UIPAth

Tags: uipath

Using UIpath trying to open an URL. I am able to do it. But the requirement is i want to open it in **reader mode**. How can i do that?

Browser i am using is Chrome.
I have enabled the Reader mode flag. I am able to manually open the reader mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I followed the extension method you suggested. I added the reader mode extension and pinned it near the address bar. So i was able to select it easily once the page is loaded. Thank You so much @churchill291

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question to answer. I assume that reader mode is the google chrome extension [Reader Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reader-mode/llimhhconnjiflfimocjggfjdlmlhblm?hl=en). I can think of two potential solutions:

1. You can use the start process activity and pass the app argument [--load-extension](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension). This may or may not work depending on the specific behavior of the chrome extension.
2. You could use the click image activity and navigate the google chrome user interface as you normally would to enable the reader mode. This ensures that you wouldn't need html/css anchors.

Not sure if this helps any, but hopefully you figure your problem out soon!

Comment: Thank You Churchill..the URL will be Data driven from excel provided.. So they vl be dynamic always..hope the xpath for reader option(near the address bar) wont change. i am trying to capture xpath and give a shot. Hope it will work. Let me kn incase u find any better options

Comment: Finally found the solution. I followed the extension method you suggested. I added the reader mode extension and pinned it near the address bar. So i was able to select it easily once the page is loaded. Thank You so much @churchill291.